# Asumming a quantum computer gets deployed. Is it safe to prune the witness area and make blocks 1MB again?

Tags: quantum-computing, witness-data

Assuming a quantum computer gets deployed. ECDSA doesn't prove anything anymore. Can we prune the witness area to save space and turn old transactions into a proper anyone can spend?

Comment: If ECDSA is broken, aren't pre-segwit transactions also vulnerable? What would this gain?

Comment: it would prune storage (save unnecessarily occupied disk space) after the point when segwit gained traction. It will also prune the ordinal spam

Comment: Why not prune everything  vulnerable to a break of ECDSA?

Comment: Good idea. And soft fork in a new postsegwit area for postquantum sigs.

Answer (score 4):

> Can we prune the witness area to save space

You can so do today already, with a pruned node. It precludes the ability to let other post-segwit nodes synchronize from you, and loses the ability to audit which participant(s) spent coins in case of a multisig. Other than that, it's perfectly feasible today; it's not done because it's much easier to prune everything past a certain point (rather than just witness data).

> and turn old transactions into a proper anyone can spend?

That is unrelated, and would require a hard fork. Without witness data, no pre-hardfork post-segwit node will be able to synchronize.

From comments:

> Good idea. And soft fork in a new postsegwit area for postquantum sigs.

You don't need a post-segwit area for that. Segwit v0 and v1 use ECDSA and Schnorr/BIP340 signatures respectively, but v2 or other future versions could be introduced that use post-quantum signatures.

Comment: > Without witness data, no pre-hardfork post-segwit node will be able to synchronize. ... I doubt this is the case. As the quantum computer can feed garbage signatures to pre-hardfork post-segwit node and cause bugs anyway.

Comment: That would require the quantum computer to forge PoW (as the witness data is committed to by PoW), which very likely remains nontrivial even with powerful quantum computers (you get the sqrt() Grover's quantum speedup, but not the polynomial Shor speedup).